# Neither handleIntent nor onCreate being called in Searchable Activity

Tags: java, android

I know there are many questions like this on here, and I have looked at many of them, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567796/android-assisted-search-the-search-button-does-not-invoke-the-searchable-activi) and all of the questions it references, but I still have no solution.  The problem is that I have followed the Android Developer guide on using the search widget, but when I open my app and hit the search widget, the onNewIntent method never gets called.  I put a Log.e into the handleIntent method so I could check if everything was connecting before I moved on to the next part of the function, but it never gets called.  I thought the issue might be in the MainActivity in the onCreateOptionsMenu, if maybe I'm not calling something right there. This is my first time trying to do this, and I'd really appreciate any kind of help on this issue, thanks.

Here is my SearchableActivity:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    DatabaseTable db= new DatabaseTable(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchable);

//        get the intent sent when user searches from search widget, verify the action and extract what is typed in
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        handleIntent(intent);

        }


    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Cursor c = db.getWordMatches(query, null);
            Log.e("Search Operation", "Database searched");

            System.out.println(R.string.app_name);


            //still need to process Cursor and display results
        }
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
        // call detail activity for clicked entry
    }



    private void doSearch(String queryStr) {
        // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter
        // and set it
    }




}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    package="com.gmd.referenceapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/nist_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
            android:value="com.example.SearchActivity" />

        <!-- main activity below, will be a home screen -->
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- //the physical constants overview page, will hopefully split into smaller categories -->
        <activity
            android:name=".FundamentalPhysicalConstants"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />

        <!-- searchable activity, performs searches and presents results -->


        <activity android:name=".SearchableActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".ConstantSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="query"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name=".ExampleListView" />
        <activity android:name=".CommonConstants" />
        <activity android:name=".ElectromagneticConstants" />
        <activity android:name=".AtomicNuclearConstants" />
        <activity android:name=".PhysicoChemicalConstants" />
        <activity android:name=".ReferenceLinks" />
        <activity android:name=".SIBaseUnits"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Searchable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">

</searchable>
```

Database Table:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import com.gmd.referenceapplication.R;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by gmd on 6/8/2016.
 */
public class DatabaseTable {


    public static final String TAG = "ConstantDatabase";

    //the columns included in the table
    public static final String COL_QUANTITY = "QUANTIY";
    public static final String COL_VALUE = "VALUE";
    public static final String COL_UNCERTAINTY = "UNCERTAINTY";
    public static final String COL_UNIT = "UNIT";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CONSTANTS";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "FTS";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    private final DatabaseOpenHelper mDatabaseOpenHelper;



    public DatabaseTable(Context context){
        mDatabaseOpenHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private final Context mHelperContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

        private static final String FTS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE +
                        " USING fts3 (" +
                        COL_QUANTITY + ", " +
                        COL_VALUE + "," +
                        COL_UNCERTAINTY + "," +
                        COL_UNIT + ")";

        public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.e("Database Operation", "Database Created / Opened...");
            mHelperContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            mDatabase = db;
            mDatabase.execSQL(FTS_TABLE_CREATE);
            Log.e("Database Operation", "Constants Table Created ...");
            loadConstants();
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }


//        populating the virtual table with a string reading code


        private void loadConstants() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        loadConstantss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            Log.e("Loading", "Constants Table Populated ...");
        }

        private void loadConstantss() throws IOException {
            final Resources resources = mHelperContext.getResources();
            InputStream inputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.txt);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strings = TextUtils.split(line, ",");
                    if (strings.length < 4) continue;
                    long id = addConstant(strings[0].trim(), strings[1].trim(), strings[2].trim(), strings[3].trim());
                    if (id < 0) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "unable to add word: " + strings[0].trim());
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        public long addConstant(String quantity, String value, String uncertainty, String unit) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(COL_QUANTITY, quantity);
            initialValues.put(COL_VALUE, value);
            initialValues.put(COL_UNCERTAINTY, uncertainty);
            initialValues.put(COL_UNIT, unit);


            return mDatabase.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }






    }

    public Cursor getWordMatches(String query, String[] columns) {
        String selection = COL_QUANTITY + " MATCH ?";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {query+"*"};

        return query(selection, selectionArgs, columns);
    }

    public Cursor query(String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String[] columns) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);

        Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(),
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.app.SearchableInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseTable dbHelper = new DatabaseTable(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);











    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow, menu);


        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                //search button is pressed
                dbHelper.getWordMatches(query,null);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // User changed the text
                return true;
            }
        });

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;

    }





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.constants:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FundamentalPhysicalConstants.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.joes_rules:
                //go to rules
                //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExampleListView.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.home:
                //Go back to the home screen
                return true;

            case R.id.search:
                //open search
                return true;

            case R.id.links:
                //go to referencelinks
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ReferenceLinks.class));
                return true;

            case R.id.base_units:
                //go to baseunits
                startActivity(new Intent(this, SIBaseUnits.class));
                return true;


            default:
                // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
                // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is if you need `searchable xml` and `SearchableActivity` at all

Comment: @pskink I'm wondering that myself, but I think I at least need searchable.xml for formatting purposes

Comment: what do you want to do with your `SearchView searchView`?

Comment: I use it to set the onQueryTextListener

Comment: yes i see it, but whats your goal? do you want a dropdown menu (like auto complete text view) with matching items?

Comment: oh, sorry, it is part of an action bar, and it creates the search box, and then I would like for it to return the results in a listView

Comment: so just call `adapter.getFilter().filter(...)`  inside `onQueryTextChange`, see [here](http://pastebin.com/K3FXeFMf) on how it works (it uses EditText, not SearchView but the idea is the same)

Comment: thank you, the link was helpful